# Transit between terminals at Dubai airport

Tags: indian-citizens, international-travel, dubai, jet-airways, flydubai

I will be traveling from Bombay to Tbilisi with a halt at Dubai.

Now the arrival at Dubai is in terminal 1 by jet airways and departure is from terminal 2 by fly Dubai.
The transit time is 7 hours and 30 minutes.
Is there a shuttle service within the airport for which I will not require a transit visa or will I have to leave through immigration and then travel outside by road to terminal 2 for which I will require a visa.
I'll be traveling with my Indian passport.

PS. I have spoken to jet airways and they said they will give my boarding pass for flydubai in Bombay itself, but they are not sure with the visa.